# Display Jenkins build number and other build information in spring MVCproject

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, spring-boot, jenkins

I have requirement to show the Jenkins build number and build time in the project web layer inorder do so I noticed a few issues in my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather then taking this approach I used the buildnumber-maven-plugin to write the build, version and other required information to build-numebr properties files and passed it to the UI.

Below is the code that needs to be added to the pom and restcontroller that pulls the information.

```js
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>create</goal>
                <goal>create-metadata</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <outputDirectory>./src/main/resources</outputDirectory>
        <outputName>buildNumber.properties</outputName>
        <addOutputDirectoryToResources>true</addOutputDirectoryToResources>
        <timestampPropertyName>buildDatetime</timestampPropertyName>
        <doCheck>true</doCheck>
        <doUpdate>true</doUpdate>
        <timestampFormat>MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss</timestampFormat>
        <format>{0}</format>
        <properties>
            <buildNumber>${buildNumber}</buildNumber>
        </properties>
        <revisionOnScmFailure>true</revisionOnScmFailure>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

```
@RestController
@Configuration
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:buildNumber.properties")
public class VersionProfiler extends AbstractController {

    @Value("${version}")
    private String ver;

    @RequestMapping(value="/version", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getVersion(){
        return ver;
    }
}
```